# Extracting a jar file to a specific path using java runtime

Tags: java, command-line, runtime

I'm using the following command in runtime to extract a jar to a specific path, but the file is extracted in my class exe path. 
**cmd="cmd /c cd F: && cd F:\workFolder\ProcessFile\ProcessJar\PJar && jar xvf F:\workFolder\ProcessFile\ProcessJar\agconfig.jar"**

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
```

Suppose, I'm executing the above code in E:\, then the jar file is extracted in the same path. 
Kindly help me to extract the jar in specified path (`F:\workFolder\ProcessFile\ProcessJar\PJar`)

Comment: You can also use `unzip -d` to set the directory. Note: jars are just zip files. See reference for unzip: http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip

Comment: *"to extract a jar to a specific path"*  Why?

Comment: Thanks stephan for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make system calls from a java application, if you can also solve the problem using java code.

You can do it in java with `java.util.zip.*`.

See [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/UnZipprintorunzipaJARorPKZIPfileusingjavautilzip.htm).

Comment: you right, I have already tried with zip, but some of the jar files are not extracted due to rights, so only i'm trying with runtime.